# trunc and round function in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, truncate, rounding, negative-number

Is trunc and round the same with negative arguments?

```
       SQL> select round(123456.76,-4) from dual;

        ROUND(123456.76,-4)
         -------------------
         120000

         SQL> select trunc(123456.76,-4) from dual;

          TRUNC(123456.76,-4)
          -------------------
         120000
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, behavior depends on the value of the significant digit (the 3rd digit (the 3) is the significant one in your case, as it is below  5 `round` and `trunc` do the same )

try `select trunc(125456.76,-4) from dual` (result is 120000) vs  `select round(125456.76,-4) from dual` (result is 130000). Now when the significant digit is 5 (or higher) the results of `trunc` and `round` differ.

Comment: @lakshganga: Note that if an answer solves your issue/problem, you can [accept it formally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work "How does accepting an answer work?").

Answer (score 1):

`ROUND` is related to round figure of given value.

`TRUNC` is related to truncation of given values.

In `round` case of given example, four places till 4th place prior to decimal point padded with 0.

But in `trunc` case, four places till 4th place prior to decimal point replacd with 0.

Answer (score 0):

`TRUNC` - depending on second parameter it returns specified decimal places that is specified in second argument. Ex:

```sql
trunc(25.656) -- 25
trunc(25.656, 1) -- 25.6
trunc(25.656, 2) -- 25.65
```

`ROUND` - round off the given number to the nearest value. Ex:

```sql
round(66) -- 70
round(64) -- 60
round(65.7) -- 66
round(65.3) -- 65
```

Comment: Please provide explanation to  your code. And remove code formatting from explanation